# Google generative api with palm: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client, palm-api, google-generativeai

I have been trying to use the Palm API and the palm.chat() function with google's new generative api. I've been in a maze of documentation and errors and I can't seem to get past this one. My code is very simple, and the error is coming from a simple request with palm.chat(). I have an API key that works when I test it with curl. I also downloaded credentials. I set up an OAuth consent screen, because I thought that might help me add the scope that I need, but I can't see what the scope requirement would be for palm.chat. Here is my code:

```
import google.generativeai as palm
import os
palm.configure(api_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']='XXXXXXXXX/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json'

response = palm.chat(messages='Hello')

response.last
```

The exact error I am getting is:

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable
> raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
> google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
> domain: "googleapis.com"
> metadata {
> key: "method"
> value: "google.ai.generativelanguage.v1beta2.TextService.GenerateText"
> }
> metadata {
> key: "service"
> value: "generativelanguage.googleapis.com"
> }

I have no idea what I am doing wrong and I've been working in circles to solve this error all day. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something was wrong with the python/pip versions, ended up switching to a different device and everything worked perfectly first try.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error when using `virtualenv`, but when I switched to `pyenv` with the same code, it worked fine. I suppose that means it was something wrong with the python environment, I'm not really sure. In addition, you don't even need to install Google Cloud CLI since you have the API key.

For more details, please refer to https://github.com/google/generative-ai-python/issues/50

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution would be to stick with using the API key on its own, but if you must use ADCs, you can use `gcloud` to set the scopes:

```bash
gcloud config set account your@account.com
gcloud config set project name-of-your-cloud-project

gcloud auth application-default login --scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
```

And don't mix credentials - either use the API key *or* the ADCs, but not both. It might work, but it's unclear what auth mechanism will take precedence in any given code path.

More detail in [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/generative-ai-python/issues/8#issuecomment-1546498351).

Comment: I tried using just the API key and just the ADC but the API key gives the same error and the gcloud commands say invalid scopes.

Comment: get same error: Run with only key gives:     google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials..Add set default credentials: gcloud auth application-default login --project palm-demo-393701 --scopes googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform} gives error: PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes Added: {googleapis.com/auth/generative-language to scope get: Error 400: invalid_scope

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working on a different computer. I suspected that there was something corrupt in one of the modules. Created a req.txt file containing the following modules:
`cachetools-5.3.1 google-ai-generativelanguage-0.2.0 google-api-core-2.11.1 google-auth-2.22.0 google-generativeai-0.1.0 googleapis-common-protos-1.59.1 grpcio-1.56.2 grpcio-status-1.56.2 proto-plus-1.22.3 protobuf-4.23.4 pyasn1-0.5.0 pyasn1-modules-0.3.0 rsa-4.9`
Ran:
`pip uninstall -y -r reqs.txt pip install google-generativeai`
It is now working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error trying to use langchain `VirtualEmbeddings()`. Inside the virtualenv just needed to do `gcloud auth application-default login` and error went away.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to authenticate with credentials instead of api_key, that means you need to generate it first.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('./credentials.json')
palm.configure(credentials=credentials)
print([m for m in palm.list_models() ]) # should work!
```

However, I support the idea something is corrupted or there is a bug in the generativeai library, this issue is only happening to me in a local Jupiter kernel, but running a python script, curl command or even Google Colab like you can see in the quick start is working good.
https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/generative-ai-docs/blob/main/site/en/tutorials/text_quickstart.ipynb
and you only need to pass an api_key.